# SQL How to Select Columns based on a condition

Tags: sql

I am creating a Stored Procedure to select Customer details. But report for each client has different requirements.

For example,
I have two tables with the same design. One is for the details and the other one is just an indicator.

```
tbl_Cust_Details
------------------------------
|Customer|Address|Contact|Qty|
|--------+-------+-------+---|
|ABC123  |NYC    |989123 |23 |
|ABD222  |WDC    |549585 |54 |
------------------------------

tbl_Column_Indicator
------------------------------
|Customer|Address|Contact|Qty|
|--------+-------+-------+---|
|ABC123  |1      |0      |1  |
|ABD222  |1      |1      |0  |
------------------------------
```

How to select columns from `tbl_Cust_Details` based on the indicators from `tbl_Column_Indicator` for each client.

```
1=show
0=hide
```

Desired output:

```
For customer ABC123:
----------------------
|Customer|Address|Qty|
|--------+-------+---|
|ABC123  |NYC    |23 |
----------------------

For customer ABD222:
--------------------------
|Customer|Address|Contact|
|--------+-------+-------|
|ABD222  |WDC    |549585 |
--------------------------
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Join them and use case statement

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple `case` expressions

```
SELECT 
          D.Customer,
          CASE(I.Address) WHEN 1 THEN D.Address ELSE NULL END [Address],
          CASE(I.Contact) WHEN 1 THEN D.Contact ELSE NULL END [Contact],
          CASE(I.Qty) WHEN 1 THEN D.Qty ELSE NULL END [Qty]
          FROM tbl_Cust_Details D
JOIN tbl_Column_Indicator I ON I.Customer = D.Customer
```

Result :

```
Customer    Address Contact Qty
ABC123      NYC     NULL    23
ABD222      WDC     549585  NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @Customer VARCHAR(20) ='ABC123'

DECLARE @SqlColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) ='[Customer]'
SELECT TOP 1 @SqlColumns = @SqlColumns +
    CASE WHEN Address = 1 THEN ', [Address]' ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN Contact = 1 THEN ', [Contact]' ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN Qty = 1 THEN ', [Qty]' ELSE '' END 
FROM tbl_Column_Indicator WHERE Customer = @Customer

DECLARE @SqlText NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ' + @SqlColumns + ' FROM tbl_Cust_Details WHERE Customer =''' + @Customer + ''''

EXEC (@SqlText)
```

Result for Customer 'ABC123'

```
Customer   Address    Qty
---------- ---------- -----------
ABC123     NYC        23
```

for Customer 'ABD222'

```
Customer   Address    Contact
---------- ---------- -----------
ABD222     WDC        549585
```